# Unable to fetch streaming links of different episodes from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape streaming links of different episodes from a [webpage](https://anime-hayai.com/880/) using requests. There are 20 episode links in there (10 for hd and 10 for regular). This is one such [url](https://anime-hayai.com/play/29610/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%B5%E0%B9%88-1-hd.html) to an episode and this is the [streaming link](https://stream.anime-hayai.com/videoplayback?id=6o7ov8-mxpu0aKZQYs7Eps2m0M2sh4pmm2l3e55jpqbEpc_Q1Z7ZhJGVk2ymaJhSteDG5NLdkaaVco5pkWdyfppmc5uWoouZkd_YtciZhXBhaJ9mcI_e) of that episode I wish to grab.

My current script can fetch all the episode links flawlessly but I can't figure out how to grab the streaming links of those episodes using requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://anime-hayai.com/880/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("#episode p:has(> span > a) > span > a"):
        episode_link = item.get("href")
        resp = s.get(episode_link)
        print(resp.content)
```

Comment: What do you get?  Those URLs are all in Thai, so you will need to be extra careful in how you handle the character sets.

Comment: Since streaming links are loaded dynamically, they are not present in page source. I even tried to look for the videoplayback ids within script tags but no luck.

Comment: It's possible they have done so intentionally, to prevent people from stealing their copyrighted material.

Comment: The page in your code returns 404.

Comment: I recheked status couple of times and found 200 @baduker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment of @SMTH, the HTML component containing the streaming link is loaded dynamically through JavaScript inside the page. It is still possible to recover the links using [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

In order for the following code to work you have to install Chrome and the corresponding version of Chromedriver (the provided code has been tested using version Google Chrome 96):

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver_path = "<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE>"
s = Service(driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)


link = 'https://anime-hayai.com/880/'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("#episode p:has(> span > a) > span > a"):

        episode_link = item.get("href")
        resp = s.get(episode_link)
        driver.get(episode_link)

        # I had to scroll down to the bottom in order 
        # to trigger the JavaScript execution, 
        # this line could be not necessary for your case
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") 

        time.sleep(5) # Wait for JavaScript to fetch links

        # The video is inside an Iframe, you need to switch to it
        frame  = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
        
        # The Iframe has an inner Ifram with the actual video
        frame  = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe")
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

        # The link of the video is in an element with class "jw-reset"
        elems = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "jw-reset")

        for elem in elems:
                # Several elements have that class
                stream_link = elem.get_attribute("src")
                # But only one has the src attribute
                if stream_link is not None:
                        print(stream_link)
```

This code will print on screen all the streaming links. You can redirect this output to a file or add a the episode title before the link.